# Mongoose update pre hook - extra database writes

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am considering adding a pre-save update hook to all of my schemas in mongoose using a global plugin.

[The manual recommends](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) putting a separate update command in the pre-hook, because `this` refers to the query insetad of the document:

```
schema.pre('update', function() {
  this.update({},{ $set: { updatedAt: new Date() } });
});
```

Does the code above cause extra database writes?  Does this method create a separate db update for the calling `update` and another write for the hook `update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per `update` [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js#L1923) and [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update), this code

```
this.update({},{ $set: { updatedAt: new Date() } });
```

belong to

```
update(criteria, doc)
```

It does NOT execute, it only add `$set: { updatedAt: new Date() }` to the `update operation` before `update` happens.

> Does the code above cause extra database writes?

No,

> Does this method create a separate db update for the calling update and another write for the hook update?

No,

Comment: Ok, so the key is to not pass a callback and not call `exec()` before finished building the query.  The plugin starts building the query, and then the calling `update()` finishes building the query before execution occurs.